# Inaccessible host: `amplify-***-deployment.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com' at port `undefined'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am trying to do an 'amplify push' to my environment but keep getting this error.
Please help.

*Full message:*
*An error occurred during the push operation: Inaccessible host: `amplify-berry-akbox-184738-deployment.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com' at port` undefined'. This service may not be available in the `ap-southeast-1' region.
⚠️ Review the Amplify CLI troubleshooting guide for potential next steps: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/*

Comment: This is s3 endpoint, not amplify. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: this is the deployment bucket for it. this is the issue i am getting when i do a 'amplify push', even when i do a 'amplify env checkout akbox'

Comment: @Marcin Amplify uses S3 bucket as deployment folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating the Amplify CLI to the latest version solved the problem.

```
$ amplify —v
8.1.0
$ npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
$ amplify -v
8.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was caused by my antivirus and firewall. Try to turn it off do the push operation and set it back this worked for me